# PHP mysql leaving out rows

Tags: php, mysql

So I am having issues with the first row of the database being left out, not sure as to why yet. Here is the code in a nutshell, leaving out the connection part and such.

```
$tickets="tickets";
$sql_ticket="SELECT * FROM $tickets WHERE username='$user'";
$ticket_query=mysql_query($sql_ticket);
$ticket_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($ticket_query);
while($ticket_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($ticket_query)){
// echoing in tables
}
```

Comment: Just read the code, this is quite obvious.... If you don't see the error, make sure you understand what each line does. This will be a good exercise.

Comment: Please do not continue using mysql_-class functions. Either use mysqli_, MYSQLI::, or PDO. See php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Every call to `mysql_fecch_assoc()` advances the record pointer one row. So when you enter your loop, it's already at the second row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
$ticket_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($ticket_query);
```

as you are fetching 1st row outside of your loop. Corrected code should be:

```
$tickets="tickets";
$sql_ticket="SELECT * FROM $tickets WHERE username='$user'";
$ticket_query=mysql_query($sql_ticket);
while($ticket_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($ticket_query)){
   // echoing in tables
}
```

Comment: Ah right, so I already assigned the first line by doing this I suppose?

Comment: Exactly, that was your bug.